# How to create a class dynamically in a Blackberry project that uses Eclipse plugin?

Tags: blackberry

How to create a class dynamically in a Blackberry project that uses Eclipse plugin?

My requirement: Suppose on click of a button a new class with a given name should be created. Methods and fields should be added and 
then I should make use of that class 
object. Is this possible in Blackberry?

Below are the steps I have done.

1. Get third party jars like ASM, javassist
2. Try to use them in project

but, I am getting verification errors when deploy to the device. So, is there a native api in RIM or any other alternative?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. But why would you need such design?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There is always some other way.

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry Java does not support the full set of reflection capabilities that you would expect in Standard Java (J2SE).

So, you won't be able to dynamically create a class, add methods, and then call them.

For the most part, BlackBerry is Java 1.3.  If you tweak your development environment, you can get access to some newer features *at compile time*.  But, in terms of the runtime code, you're limited to 1.3.

[Javassist](https://source.jboss.org/browse/Javassist) is based on Java APIs that don't exist in the 1.3 runtime that BlackBerry has, so it won't be of much help :(

Hopefully, someone else will chime in, but I don't know that this is something that's possible on BlackBerry Java.